# Proving that finding wheel subgraphs is NP-complete

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete

Can you help me with this problem ?

> Given an undirected graph $G$ and an integer $n$, prove that determining whether the graph has wheel on $n$ vertices $W_{n}$ (a wheel $W_{i}$ is such that $i$ nodes form a cycle and a $i+1$st node is connected to all other nodes, resulting in $2i$ edges) is NP-complete.

Comment: This object is also often referred to as the _Wheel on $n$ vertices_, and denoted $W_n$.

Comment: @Raphael,Hamiltonian Cycle approach does not seems to be valid because for this problem one needs to show that finding certain SUBGRAPH is an NP-Complete problem. Hamiltonian Cycle does not deal with subgraphs... Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Hamiltonian Cycle is $NP$-Complete.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [advice in our reference post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/11215/98), check out [related NP-complete problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_NP-complete_problems#Subgraphs_and_supergraphs) in order to find a suitable reduction partner.

> [Hamiltonian cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) does indeed look promising: note that $W_n$ contains a simple cycle.