# Need Help Reducing Subset Sum to Show a Problem is NP-Complete

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, proof-techniques

I want to show that the following problem is NP-Complete:

For a set of vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n \in \mathbb{N}^d$ and an integer $k$, does there exist a subset $S \subseteq \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, such that $S$ has $k$ elements and all coordinates in the vector $\sum\limits_{x\in S} v_x$ are powers of two?

I'm quite certain that establishing a reduction from a known NP-Complete problem: the Knapsack Problem, Subset Sum or Vector Subset Sum (see section 4.3 [here](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs573/fa2013/lec/slides/04_notes.pdf)) to this problem is the correct way to approach this problem, but I'm having difficulty 
figuring out how to exactly construct the reduction.

Concerning Subset Sum with a set $S$ and an integer $n$, I've tried taking one of the integer compositions of $n$, then splitting it up into its binary representation, and using that to dictate a desired vector. Then I would construct vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ from the elements of $S$. But how do I create the input $k$?

One of the main issues here is that Subset Sum with a fixed subset size is not NP-complete. How do I work around that? Moreover, one of the trickier aspects of the problem is generalizing subset sum such that success is reported if some subset sums to *any* power of two. I don't see how not to appeal to multiple sub-instances of subset sum...

Is this the right approach? (If not, how should I do it?) What am I missing? How do I prove this?

Comment: Hint: $d = 1$ should suffice.

Comment: Do you know how to such reductions in general? You could combine Yuval's great hint with [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/what-are-common-techniques-for-reducing-problems-to-each-other), and most likely solve the problem :-)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I've considered the case for $d=1$. But this leaves me with the following question: for a set of integers X, does there exist a k-element subset S of X such that $\sum_S$ is a power of two? How to show that this is NP-Complete is not clear to me, because the Subset Sum problem with a fixed subset size is not NP-complete. I don't see the immediate reduction. I assume I have to show that while the fixed subset reduces the computational complexity of the problem, the "is a power of two" adds complexity so that the overall problem is still NP-Complete? Your input would be appreciated.

Comment: @Juho do you have any suggestions how to tackle this?

Comment: Is $k$ a constant or an input? That is, can the solution run in time $\Theta(n^k)$ or must it run in time polynomial in $k$?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some hints:

1. Focus on the case $d = 1$.
2. Given a target $T$ in SUBSET-SUM, we can change it to a target $T'$ by adding the number $T' - T$; this should work if $T'$ is sufficiently large.
3. Given a SUBSET-SUM without constraints on the size of the subset, we can get an equivalent problem with such a constraint by adding a suitable number of zeroes to the (multi)set.

If we insist on a set, we need to do more cunning in 3.

Comment: Hint #3 was extremely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Now I am just wondering about the second part of your hint: changing a target is helpful, but I don't see how it lets me generalize to any power of two, rather than a specific one...

Comment: @Newb You're right, my hints don't address this issue. Time for you to think.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint #1**: focus on $d=1$, as Yuval suggests.

**Hint #2**: suppose we're given an instance of [the subset-sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), i.e., we're given some integers
$x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$.

Now suppose we let $v_1=42x_1$, ..., $v_n = 42x_n$.  Think about whether there is a subset of $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ that sums to a power of two.  When does that happen?  What's the condition under which $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ has a subset that sums to a power of two?

The answer looks unhelpful, but notice that $42$ is arbitrary.  What if we replace $42$ with some other constant $c$, and then ask the same question?  Can you find some other constant $c$ (instead of $42$) where the condition when $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ has a subset that sums to a power of two is more convenient?

**Hint #3**: to start with, I suggest you artificially consider $0$ to be a power of two (even though I know it isn't really a power of two) and you ignore the constraint on the size of the subset.  Once you can solve that variation, I suggest you go back to the original problem: a slight tweak to your construction should take care of them.

**Reminder**: Don't forget to attribute all your sources, when you write up the solution to your exercise.  Your teachers read the Internet too. :-)

Comment: Interesting. Your hint w/r/t/ the constant has really given me something to think about...

Comment: The constant is giving me some trouble, and I can't see how this leads to the solution. I've fiddled with prime factorizations, adding/removing terms, etc., but I still don't see how the constant helps to find whether or not the subset sums to a power of two, even for the smallest power, $2^0=1$.