# NP-Complete Proof of k sized common set

Tags: np-complete, proof-techniques

**Input:** A set $U= \{w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n\}$, subsets $S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_m$ of $U$ and integer $k$.
**Question:** Is there a subset with $k$ elements of $U$ which intersects of every $S_i$?

Which reduction should i use to prove that this is np-complete ?

**Hint:** Reduction from vertex cover.

Comment: What problems do you know that might work? Do you know anything that sounds similar? There are a number of possibilities here (your problem is a very well known one).

Comment: It reminds a little bit of set cover. I tried to turn the problem into a graph but i couldn't think anything past this stage.(Man, i am sorry. I didnt know that this is well known problem. I studying on my own and i having problem with these kind of problems. May be i am stupid or i don't have sufficient knowlegde. I would i appreciate if you could suggest ways to gain experience).

Comment: no need for apologies, the comment that it is well known was just a gentle hint that the answer is out there. You are right to think of set cover - it's a _very_ closely related problem. In fact there is a reduction from Set Cover, and turning Set Cover and this problem into the right sort of graph might help you see it (think bipartite). As for gaining experience, you're on the right track, it just takes practice and time, and it's not always easy.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot. Would you mind sharing any helpful resources ? I really want to improve.

Comment: Reopened, because the question is answerable. Please do post an answer — but note that “reduction from vertex cover” isn't an answer. An answer would explain how and why that helps.

Comment: @Gilles, I expect the reason this was closed by the community is not because it is unanswerable, but rather because it violates [our policy](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/751) on exercise problems.  Therefore, I think it should remain closed until it is edited in line with our policies.  Overriding the close votes prevents the original close-voters from re-voting to close and reduces the incentive to improve the question in line with our policies.

Comment: hardstudent, What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We want to help you with your specific problems, not just solve your exercise for you. However, as it is we don't know what this problem is and thus how to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion, and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).  I also encourage you to review [our reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11209/755). If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: @D.W. We don't have a policy that states that such questions should be closed. You linked to an [answer](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/751) with a score of 0 in a thread that isn't about acceptable questions, this isn't a policy. In http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question, none of the answers call for closing such questions. This question is not an ultra-specific apply-the-steps question, it calls for an answer with teachable content. It's usefully answerable and on-topic, so I don't see on what basis you would close it.

Comment: Sorry, i'm lost. First of all its not homework, i'm just trying to solve past exams questions. Secondly ,the only thing i asked, was a hint because i didn't know what reduction should i use. As by now, i have found an answer and i thought i should it as a hint.

Comment: @Gilles, Opinions may differ, but here's my view (based on Meta threads): we expect that posters should show what they've tried, and should try to identify a specific question about the wording of the question or about specific steps that they got stuck on, rather than just copy-pasting the problem statement. The close reason "unclear what you're asking" already states "Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.", which seems to fit exactly, so no extra policy is needed -- this situation is already covered by the existing close reason.

Comment: @Gilles, (continued) Anyway, opinions on how to handle these situations may reasonably differ, but re-opening such questions overrides the community's close votes, which are themselves a potential window into the community's views.

Comment: hardstudent, as the discussion in the links I cited explains, the issue isn't whether this is homework  -- the issue is that this is a problem dump.  To quote from one comment: "The problem is not whether it's homework or not, the problem is problem dumps (no matter whether it's a live exam, take-home homework, self-study, etc.)"  Problem dump means the question consists of little more than a problem statement, with little evidence of concrete attempts to solve it and no attempt to pose a more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will reduce vertex cover to our problem.

**Problem:** Vertex Cover
**Input:** Graph $G(V,E)$ and integer k
**Question:** Is there a subset $V'\subseteq$ V : $|V|\leq k$ which contains at least one vertex of each edge in $E$.

**Reduction:** For every $e_i$ edge of $G$, we build a set $S_i=\left \{u_i,v_i  \right \}$ where $u_i,v_i$ are the incident vertices of $e_i$. If there is a set with size k which intersects with every $S_i$, it means that this set contains at least one vertex of each edge in $G$. In other words its a vertex cover with size k.
 Because the reduction can be done in polynomial time and vertex cover $\in NP-Complete$, we can conclude that k sized common set is $NP-Complete$.