# Complexity if special case of SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability

I have the following problem: How to show that the special case of SAT, in which each clause has either exactly two literals or at most one negative literal, is NP-complete?

Comment: Kneejerk answer: you do so by picking a suitable hard problem and constructing a reduction. Assuming you know this, what did you try? Did you get stuck somewhere?

Comment: what did u do so far?

Answer (score 1):

You pick a problem that is NP-complete and [show a reduction](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11209/755) that shows your problem is at least as hard as that NP-complete problem.  As this is a natural exercise problem, you should practice trying it yourself -- we wouldn't be helping anyone to just spoonfeed you the solution.

Alternatively, you use [Schaefer's dichotomy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem).  (Comment: If you're just learning the subject, don't expect this to be easier than doing the reduction!  This is only if you want to go deeper on the subject.)