# Undecidability of an existential theory

Tags: computability, undecidability, first-order-logic

$F[u, u^{-1}]$ is a ring that contains the polynomials in $u$ and $u^{-1}$ with coefficients in the field $F$.

Some theorems (from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382120/ft-has-undecidable-positive-existential-theory-in-the-language-cdot) are the following:

**Theorem 1.**

> Assume that the characteristic of $F$ is zero. Then the existential theory of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, t\}$ is undecidable.

**Theorem 2.**

> Assume that $F$ has characteristic $p>2$. Then the existential theory of $F[t, t^{-1}]$ is undecidable.

**Theorem 3.**

> If the characteristic of $F$ is other than $2$, then $F[t]$ has undecidable positive existential theory in the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, t\}$.

I am looking at [the proof of Theorem 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382120/ft-has-undecidable-positive-existential-theory-in-the-language-cdot) and trying to understand the last part of it.

I understand that an existential statement of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ in the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, u\}$ is of the form 
$$\exists x_1, \dots \exists x_n \in F[u,u'] \phi(x_1, \dots , x_n)$$ 
where $\phi(x_1, \dots , x_n)$ can consist of $0$, $1$ and $u$ and has the operation $+$ and $\cdot$ between $0$, $1$, and $u$.

I have a question that is related to the [proof](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7LyulQBh6efQThrT3p3Y2lQNkE/view) of Theorem $3$.

When we know that the existential theory of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ is undecidable in the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, u\}$ and we want to show that the existential theory of $F[u, u^{-1}]$ is undecidable also in the language $\{+, \cdot , 0, 1, (u+u^{-1})/2\}$, is it correct that we have to reduce the second problem to the first one?

Comment: If you're not sure which way the reduction works, try working it out. Then you'll know for sure.

Comment: I have edited your post to ask a single question.  In the future, it's normally best to ask only one question per question.  Also, "please check whether my answer is correct" questions are off-topic here, as only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors, so I removed that part. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/); in the future, you should instead formulate a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about.

Comment: Please refer to the explanation of reductions at http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9556/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11209/755.  It looks to me like that answers your question about which way the reduction needs to go.  (possible duplicate?)  If it's still unclear, I suggest editing the question to explain why specifically you are unsure about which way the reduction needs to go, given that information.