# Proving a language is neither Recursively Enumerable nor co-Recursively Enumerable

Tags: turing-machines, proof-techniques, undecidability

$$L = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid \text{\(M\) is a Turing Machine and \(|L(M)| = 1\)} \}$$

I have to prove that this is not R.E. and not co-R.E.

I know how to approach these kind of problems. For
$\check L = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid \text{\(M\) is a Turing Machine and \(|L(M)| \le 1\)} \}$,
Here a simple reduction from complement of HP would do the trick. (Make a TM $M'$ which on input $w$ runs $M$ on $x$ and accepts if $M$ accepts $x$. If $\langle M,x \rangle$ belongs to complement of HP then $x$ would not be accepted and hence $M'$ would reject everything thereby satisfying the $\le 1$ property. Also in case $\langle M,x \rangle$ doesn't belong to complement of HP, $M'$ would accept everything and hence would be $\gt 1$. Thus we know that the complement of HP is reducible to $\check L$. Hence $\check L$ is not RE.)

But in the main problem I don't have an inequality and I am stuck with how to approach such problems. I would face the same problem while proving $L'$ (complement of $L$) as not RE for proving $L$ as not co RE.

Comment: See also [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/what-are-common-techniques-for-reducing-problems-to-each-other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is by showing there do not exist Turing machines that accept  $L_3$ or $\overline L$. But probably that is simply restating the question.

$L_u$, the universal language, is non-recursive but RE language. If we reduce $L_u \leq_M L$ then $L$ cannot be co-RE. If we reduce $L_u \leq_M \overline{L}$ then $L$ cannot be RE.

Let us  first do the reduction $L_u \leq_M L$.

We shall reduce $\langle M,w\rangle$ to a Turing machine $M'$ as follows:
$M'$ rejects all inputs other than $w$. If the input is $w$ then it runs as Turing Machine $M$ on $w$. This gives us $\langle M,w\rangle \in L_u$ iff $M' = f(\langle M,w\rangle) \in L$.

Hence $L_u \leq_M L$. Therefore $L$ cannot be co-RE. Otherwise $L_u$ will become recursive.

Next we do the reduction $L_u \leq_M \overline L$.

We shall reduce $\langle M,w\rangle$ to a Turing machine $M''$ as follows: Let $w'$ be a string other than $w$.
$M''$ rejects all inputs other than $w$ and $w'$. If the input in $w'$ then $M''$ accepts the input. If the input is $w$ then it runs as Turing Machine $M$ on $w$. This gives us $\langle M,w\rangle \in L_u$ iff $M''= f(\langle M,w\rangle) \not\in L$, that is, $\langle M,w\rangle \in L_u$ iff $M'' \in \overline L$.

Hence $L_u \leq_M \overline{L}$. Therefore $L$ cannot be RE. Otherwise $L_u$ will become recursive.

If we combine the results, $L$ is neither RE nor co-RE.

Comment: How do we make sure that our TM rejects "all inputs other than w"? Isn't w a general representation of an input and not the input itself?

Comment: Also if I wish to prove for |L(M)| = 2, would it be correct to follow the same approach and accept only two inputs and reject everything else? Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Yeh, sure, for any |L(M)| = k.

Comment: I misread the Theorem stating that if A ≤ B then if B is Turing Recognizable, A is too. I read it the other way round and was thus stuck with this. Thanks a lot!