# Reducing partition to a partition where sum(partition1) = 3 times sum(partition2)

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, decision-problem, partitions

Given the following NP-complete problem:

> **PARTITION**
>
> **Input:** A list of positive integers $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$.
>
> **Question:** Can the list be partitioned into $2$ parts, $A_1$ and $A_2$, such that the sum of each part is the same?

Now I want to reduce PARTITION to the following problem:

> **TRIPLE-SUM**
>
> **Input:** A list of positive integers $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$.
>
> **Question:** Can the list be partitioned into $2$ parts, $A_1$ and $A_2$, such that the sum of the numbers in $A_1$ is exactly *three*
>   times the sum of the numbers in $A_2$?

I'm struggling to see how the transformation can take place. I've tried transforming the list $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ by multiplying each element by $3$ (stupid... I know...) but everything I tried failed. Is there a way to perform this reduction? Does it even require to modify the input list?

Comment: Perhaps you should spend a few more days on this problem. Reductions can be tricky. You might want to take a look at the related problem of SUBSET-SUM.

Comment: I think there is a way to do the reduction by adding an additional number to the input. Just a single number. Maybe i'm telling you too much…

Comment: @rotia: Clever. I figured out a much more complicated way that worked by adding n numbers very close to the original ones...

Comment: [Our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/what-are-common-techniques-for-reducing-problems-to-each-other) may provide some inspiration.

Comment: @rotia Hmm, that makes me think - can we reduce PARTITION to DOUBLE-SUM? (Trying to add The Number in this case does not work)

Comment: @MCT Yes, you can. You only need to add two numbers to the 2PARTITION instance