# Reduction from SAT to shortest cycle?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, reductions, satisfiability

I have been assigned a homework problem that I cannot figure out:

> Prove that SAT has a polynomial-time reduction to the language of undirected non-negative weighted graphs with simple cycle of weight less that or equal to w.

This bears a resemblance to the all-pairs shortest path problem which has polynomial-time algorithms, but I've read multiple times that this problem is np-hard (plus, I suppose it would be a cruel trick to give such an assignment).

Starting from hamcycle, I have managed to produce a reduction for several variations on this problem (e.g., tsp, longest positive path, shortest negative path), but whenever it comes to this language I can always come up with a counterexample that invalidates my attempt at a reduction.

So, is there a reduction from SAT?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of "give a man a fish, and he'll be fed for a day; teach a man to fish, and he never need be hungry again", I'll share with you some problem-solving techniques that might be helpful for approaching this problem (and other problems) -- but I'm not going to spoil it for you by solving your exercise for you.

---

Technique #1:  If you don't know how to solve a problem, change the problem: look for "nearby"/"similar" problems you do know how to solve.  If you can't reduce SAT to the original language, is there some related/variant language you *can* reduce SAT to?  You may need to try multiple variants, and get a feeling for which ones you can easily find a reduction for and which ones you struggle with.  This may give you some intuition about what the barrier/difficult part of your problem is, which may help you identify what aspect to focus your energy on.

Hint #1 (possible spoilers):

> If you changed "less than or equal to w" to "equal to w", would the problem be any easier?  What if you changed it to "greater than or equal to w"?

---

Technique #2: You can chain reductions.  If you can reduce SAT to some variant, and reduce that variant to the original problem, you're in business.

Hint #2 (possible spoilers):

> It seems that short cycles are a headache.  If you have a graph $G$, can you think of some way to transform it to remove all short cycles (without changing whether or not it contains a cycle of length $w$)?  (If you can't immediately see how to do it, can you write out a precise specification of what such an algorithm would need to do?)

---

And that's as much as I'm going to say.  It's a good exercise, and it's your exercise, so you should have the chance to play around with it and discover a solution for yourself.  It's tricky but doable.

Comment: Comment as answer because I don't have 50 reputation: I have no trouble making a reduction in the way you hint, in a few different ways. My problem is that that's as close as I can get - it's the "less than" part that I'm missing.

Comment: @user55570, please don't use the 'answer' box to post comments or request clarification.  If you've lost access to your original account, please [create an account](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/why-register) to ensure you retain access -- that way you'll be able to post comments in response to people's answers.  Also, I encourage you to [merge your two accounts](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Anyway, I edited my answer to provide some more problem-solving techniques.

Comment: Don't we already have a [place for teaching how to fish](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/what-are-common-techniques-for-reducing-problems-to-each-other)? Maybe you want to add something there.