# Any suggestions about a known NP-complete problem that can be reduced to the following problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, reductions

> Given an undirected graph $G$, where nodes represent towns and edges represent roads, and given a positive integer $k$, is there a way to build $k$ McDonald's at $k$ different towns so that every town either has its own McDonald's, or is connected by a (direct) road to a town that does have a McDonald's?

I believe that this problem is NP-complete. I am trying to find a well-known NP-complete problem, so I can use it to prove that this problem is NP-complete, too. Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion 1: read up on Vertex Cover. Suggestion 2: ask this on a different forum.  This forum is intended for current research in mathematics, as opposed to topics in undergraduate computer science.  Gerhard "Try A Computer Science Forum" Paseman, 2016.10.22.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that this is itself a well-known NP-complete problem, one of the [oldest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems).

Comment: "I believe that this problem is NP I am trying to find a well known NP complete problem, so I can use it to prove that this problem is NP-complete too." -- 1) Being NP is not the same as being NP-complete. I guess you mean the latter? 2) If this problem is indeed NP-hard, *every* NP problem reduces to it. Pick any. 3) You may profit from reading our reference questions on [basics of complexity theory](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556)  and [common techniques for coming up with reductions](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/).

Comment: @GerhardPaseman It's not (plain) Vertex Cover. For instance, a triangle requires two nodes to vertex-cover but only one node to mcdonalds-cover.

Comment: Hint: Removing set dressing, this is pretty much Set Cover.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is called [Dominating Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set), and as pointed out by Raphael in the comments it's a special case of Set Cover (for each vertex, create a set for it and its neighbours).  It's NP-hard.