# Complexity of a non-linear knapsack problem

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, np-hard, knapsack-problems, packing

Minimize

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{m_i}w_{i,j}v_{i,j}$$

subject to

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{m_i}{m_i+\sum_{j=1}^{m_i}v_{i,j}} < \theta$$

$$v_{i,j}\in\{0,1\}~\forall i,~j$$

where

- $w_{i,j}$ and $m_i$ are positive integers (constants)
- $\theta$ is a positive real number (constant)
- $v_{i,j}$ are 0-1 variables

is this problem NP-hard?

I think this is 'harder' than knapsack problem and probably should be NP-hard. I surveyed some literature but failed to understand them.

Comment: I edited to focus on the complexity part of things; once that's settled, feel free to post another question about algorithms!

Comment: That said, the issue remains: what have you tried and where did you get stuck? If research articles are not accessible to you, have you tried textbooks? Have you tried the [standard techniques](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/what-are-common-techniques-for-reducing-problems-to-each-other) of reduction?