# How to show the function is not Turing computable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Having the function:

$$f(y) = \begin{cases}
         \ 1 &\text{if }\forall n \Phi_y(n)=n\lor \Phi_y(n) \!\uparrow\\
         \ 0 &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

By the rule of thumb it should not be computable. How to prove it formally?
If it's computable, I assumed a function like this exists:
$$g(y) = \begin{cases}
         \ 1 &\text{if $f$(y) = 1 }\\
         \ 0 &\text{if $f$(y) = 0}
\end{cases}$$

I assumed $g(y)$ is computable. Now there exists a function $\Phi_{x_0}(x_0)$ which simulates $g(y)$. 
This means: $\Phi_{x_0}(x_0) \downarrow$ iff $\Phi_{x_0} (x_0) \uparrow$, which is a contradiction. Is this sufficient as a proof?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/what-are-common-techniques-for-reducing-problems-to-each-other) may be of help.

Comment: I don't quite understand your proof. Try a reduction from the halting problem.

Comment: So it's enough to show that we can map it onto the halting problem? I.e. having a set of instances of (A, D), where A is $\Phi_y(n)$ and D is some x from $N$, we get pairs in S such as ($\Phi_y$, 1), ($\Phi_y$, 2), ...., now H halts if $\Phi_y(n) $ = n. Thus we can map it onto the halting problem, therefore it's not computable?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample solution? So I could see the right way to go for exercises like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I assume this is a homework question, I won't give a fully detailed proof but rather a sketch with some gaps to fill.

Consider the function 
$$g(x)=
\begin{cases} 
  x+1 & \text{ if } \varphi_x(x)\downarrow\\
  \uparrow & \text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
This function is computable (convince yourself of that!), so it has an index $e$.

Now consider the function $f$ on $e$, then computing $f(e)$ comes down to verifying whether $\forall n\  \varphi_e(n)\uparrow$. Can you see why this contradicts that the halting problem is not computable?

Comment: Thansk for the answer! Just to make it clear, this is not a homework assignment, it's already the exam preparation :). I see that the g(x) is computable, as we can construct a turing machine for each $\Phi_x(x)$ so that if it halts it gives back the answer. However if the $\Phi_e$ halts and gives back the answer, it also won't diverge as it will halt, right? Then f(e) gives back 0. However if $\Phi_e$ diverges we still assume f(x) to give back 1 which we can never decide?

Comment: To your first question, a computation either halts (converges) or it does not halt (diverges). So of course, if it halts, it won't diverge.

Comment: And is the second question correct contradiction? :)

Comment: To your second question, $f(e)=1 \text{ if } \forall n\ \varphi_e(n)\uparrow$. This i ridiculous though, as it converges if another function diverges.

Comment: One could also define $g$ more in the light of Yuval Filmus' answer, by $g(x)=\{x+1 \text{ if } \varphi_{x_0}(x_0)\downarrow\}$ for some natural number $x_0$.
$g$ is again computable, say by $e$. Then we have solved the Halting problem as $f(e)=1$ if $\varphi_{x_0}(x_0)\uparrow$ and $f(e)=0$ if $\varphi_{x_0}(x_0)\downarrow$.

I would accept both answers, although the one using this definition is maybe a little better as it shows better how to reduce the Halting problem to $f$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to solve the halting problem using $f$. Suppose that we are given a Turing machine $T$, and we want to know whether it halts on the empty input. Construct a Turing machine $T'$ which on input $n$ runs $T$, and if it ever halts, it outputs $n+1$. So $T$ halts on the empty input iff $f(\langle T' \rangle) = 0$.

Conversely, we can calculate $f$ using an oracle for the halting problem. Given a Turing machine $T$, construct a Turing machine $T'$ which runs $T$ on all possible inputs in parallel, and stops if it finds out that $T(n) \neq n$ for some $n$. Then $f(\langle T \rangle) = 0$ iff $T'$ halts.

What we have shown is that $f$ (more exactly, the set of 1-inputs of $f$) is [$\Pi_1$-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I can only accept only the single answer as a correct one!