# Reduction without Rice's Theorem

Tags: reductions, undecidability, rice-theorem

How can I show that the following language is neither semi decidable nor co-semi decidable without using Rice's Theorem?

[image]

Further for the following language, how would I show that it IS co-semi decidable but not decidable for |Σ| > 1

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help with conceptual issues but just solving homework-style exercises for you is unlikely to really help you.

Comment: The titular question is funny, because using Rice's theorem is not a reduction. ;) That said, check out [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/what-are-common-techniques-for-reducing-problems-to-each-other)!

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. These two are indeed related -- do you see the connection?