# Collection of meta-reductions in theory of $\mathrm{NP}$-completeness

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, np-hard, np

I want to start a wiki post about meta-result of meta-reductions in the theory of $\mathrm{NP}$-completeness.

This can be regarded as a reference request post. Any links are appreciated.

At least, this can be helpful in drastically mitigating the frequently asked questions related to homework assignments that are giving so much credit to @David Richerby, @D.W., @Yuval Filmus.

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: A well-known examples is Schaefer's dichotomy theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem

Comment: Another classical result is Ladner’s theorem.

Comment: Well, one of the main objective of this question is the starting point for students seeking NP-complete reduction for homework assignment. And, Ladner's theorem rarely yields hard assignment.

Comment: We already have a [reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/what-are-common-techniques-for-reducing-problems-to-each-other) to similar effect, but answers there (and in general) should stand on their own, that is contain more than just a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### GRAPH PROPERTIES

In graph theory, a nice collection is from Figueiredo.

https://www.cos.ufrj.br/~celina/ftp/celina-lagos09.pdf

Answer (score 0):

### NODE- & EDGE- DELETION

Here, I start with some links on meta-result on the hardness of node- and edge- deletion to satisfy $\pi$ property for various classes of property $\pi$.

https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=804355
https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/ramsey/hered.pdf
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X83901014

Answer (score 0):

### DICHOTOMY THEOREMS IN LOGIC

Here, I go on to give some more material in logic.

https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00098730/document
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem