# Prove disprove an existence of mapping reduction between 2 sets

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

I am currently studying mapping reduction in computational theory and finding it hard to grasp the concept fully.

For reference, consider the following given WHILE-Prog sets:

A = { (p.d) | p doesn't halt on input d } = Complementary HALT set.
B = { p | p halts on exactly one input (the input is unknown) }

Is A < B. meaning, is there a mapping reduction from A to B?

---

Can someone suggest a hint?

knowing that A belongs to coRE did not help much. 
B doesn't seem to belong to either RE nor coRE.

Comment: Try attacking the problem directly, i.e., constructing an instance of $B$ from an instance of $A$.

Comment: @Apass.Jack, Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Apass.Jack , That's what I was trying to do, however, it seems to be very confusing. The mapping should behave as follows: 1. A -> B : it means that [p]d did not halt, so I should return a program q such that q halts on one particular input only. this is quite easy by returning a program that loopsforever on inputs different from nil. 2.  not A -> not B: this is where I am mostly confused, as if [p]d halts, I should return q such that either one of the following occurs: 1. [q] doesn't halt on any input. 2. [q] halts on at least two inputs.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.

Comment: $A = \{ (p, d) \mid p \text{ doesn't halt on input }d \}$. What is $p$? Is it a Turing machine? Or a program?

Comment: p is a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One basic idea is to observe that $B$ looks harder than $A$ since

- we need to run a given Turing machine on one given input in order to find whether the pair is in $A$ but
- we may need to run a given Turing machine on infinity many inputs in order to find whether it is in $B$.

That observation should motivate us to find a reduction from $A$ to $B$.

---

Suppose $(p,d)\in A$. Construct a machine that behaves as the following.

Upon an input string $s$, it checks whether $s$ is $d\sigma$, where $\sigma$ stand for a fixed letter in the alphabet.

- If yes, it halts.
- If no, it checks whether $s$ is $d$.

  - If no, it loops forever.
  - If yes, it simulate $p$ on $d$.

It should be routine to verify the construction above is indeed a reduction from $A$ to $B$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The course I am taking does not rely on a Turing machine even though it seems like the common way. As far as what I have learned thus far, the reduction should map instances from A TO B and from Complementary A to Complementary B.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by comparing s to dσ ? never dealt with such inputs, just tree based inputs consisting of nil's e.g (nil.nil), ((nil.nil).nil), etc.

Comment: Replace "Turing machine" and "machine" by program everywhere in the answer.

Comment: $s$ is a string. $d\sigma$ means the string that is the string $d$ followed by the letter $\sigma$. "Checking whether $s$ is $d\sigma$" just means whether the string $s$ is equal to the string $d\sigma$, i.e., whether the first letter of $s$ and that of $d$ is the same, whether the second letter of $s$ and that of $d$ is the same, ..., whether the second last letter of $s$ and the last letter of $d$ is the same, and whether the last letter of $s$ is $\sigma$. (I assume, WLOG, every input is a string over some alphabet.)

Comment: I got it! :) Thank you so much. A few things I would like to ask: 1. What guided you through the process? I am finding it hard to grasp how much it is possible to write a program that halts which relies on a program that doesn't. 2. Are there any relevant papers to review online for reference? Yet again, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Those two questions are harder to answer. 1) Pattern recognition, practice, experience and luck. 2) You could search for ["examples Turing machine reduction"](https://www.google.com/search?q=examples+of+Turing+machine+reduction). [This question and answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11209/what-are-common-techniques-for-reducing-problems-to-each-other) might be helpful.